# How to detect whether current cursor position is code-block in markdown file from lua function?

Tags: neovim, lua, filetype-markdown, plugin-treesitter

**Target:** Trying to write `lua` function that will return `true` if current cursor position in code-block in markdown, `false` if not.

**Current Status**: I have following code, that (based on tree-sitter) captures the current node, checks its type, and then checks the parent node, and so on.

```lua
local ts_utils   = require("nvim-treesitter.ts_utils")
In_md_fence = function()
    local node = ts_utils.get_node_at_cursor()
    while node do
        if node:type() == "fenced_code_block" then
            print('its fenced block')
            return true
        end
        print(node:type())
        node = node:parent()
    end

    print('finish')
    return false
end
```

**Problem**:
when I run `:lua In_md_fence()` at `range(1)` in following markdown file:

````
# hello

```python
import numpy as np
for i in range(1):
    print(i)
```

asdf as
dfadsfkjasdlfjasdl;kfjasldfjaskl
askjjfalsdkjfaksdlf
````

[image]

I got these printed:

```
integer
argument_list
call
for_statement
module
finish
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

- My expectation was it should have print `integer`,  `argument_list`, `call`, `for_statement`, `?module?`, `code_fence_content`, `fenced_code_block`

**Question**:

- Why didn't `fenced_code_block` didn't show up?
- Where did I messed up?
- How can I fix it?
- I only get expected output, if cursor was at ```` ```python ```` or ```` ``` ````, not if it was actually inside of the block.